# Sum by twos for functions on $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two double sums with the steps $2$ and I do know that one of them is smaller than the other one (due to a complicated argument), but I would like to show it with direct computation.

Let $\sideset{_2}{}\sum$ denote the sum by twos. Then I would like to show that
$$
\sideset{_2}{}\sum_{t=-m}^{m} \sideset{_2}{}\sum_{s=-n}^{n} f(t+s) \geq \sideset{_2}{}\sum_{t=n-m}^{n+m} \sideset{_2}{}\sum_{s=-t}^t f(s).
$$
for  $m,n \in \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and the function $f:\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$.

PS I tried some numbers for $n$ and $m$ and it turned out that all of them give me the equality. But still the inequality is enough for me.

Comment: Just to clarify, by "sum by twos" do you mean for example f(-t)+f(-t+2)+...+f(-t+2t)?

Comment: And actually you want the inner sum on the right to be from $-|t|$ to $|t|$, not $-t$ to $t$ right?

Comment: by `sum by twos' I mean exactly the thing that brogrenkp said. And I fix the error in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the sum in a careful array:
$$\matrix{f(-m-n)&+f(-m-n+2)&+\cdots&+f(-m+n-2)&+f(-m+n)\cr
          +f(-m-n+2)&+f(-m-n+4)&+\cdots&+f(-m+n)&+f(-m+n+2)\cr
           +\cdots\cr
          +f(m-2)&+f(m)&+\cdots&+f(m+n-4)&+f(m+n-2)\cr
          +f(m)&+f(m+2)&+\cdots&+f(m+n-2)&+f(m+n)\ .\cr}$$
If you now add all the entries in the first column and the last row you get
$$f(-m-n)+f(-m-n+2)+\cdots+f(m-2)+f(m)+f(m+2)+\cdots+f(m+n-2)+f(m+n)$$
which is
$$\sideset{_2}{}\sum_{s=-m-n}^{m+n} f(s)\ .$$
The next column and row give
$$f(-m-n+2)+f(-m-n+4)+\cdots+f(m)+\cdots+f(m+n-4)+f(m+n-2)$$
which is
$$\sideset{_2}{}\sum_{s=-m-n+2}^{m+n-2} f(s)\ ,$$
and so on.  You may have to break up into cases depending on which of $m,n$ is bigger, but if for example $n\ge m\ge0$ then the last sum will involve the leftover items from the top row only and will be
$$f(m-n)+\cdots+f(-m+n)=\sideset{_2}{}\sum_{s=m-n}^{-m+n} f(s)\ .$$
These partial sums (reading them in the reverse order from how we found them) are
$$\sideset{_2}{}\sum_{s=-t}^{t} f(s)$$
for
$$t=n-m,\ldots,n+m-2,n+m$$
and so we get exactly your RHS.  In conclusion: as you conjectured, the two double sums are equal.